# How to get the each element of a string in R

Tags: r

I have a string with the following:

```
ticker = c("BTC-USD", "^GDAXI")
```

How can I extract each element of this string, so that I can use paste0 for naming my list. Something like

```
names(Stocks) = paste0(ticker)
```

So that at the end the element in my lists have BTC-USD and then ^GDAXI as names

Thank You

Comment: You do not need `paste0` to name the list, as a matter of fact, I would keep `names(Stocks) = ticker` only. What didn't work? After that instruction what is the return value of `names(Stocks)`? Also, is the circumflex at the beginning of `"GDAXI"` a typo?

Comment: i was thinking too complicated. What you said helped me. the names in my lists are correct now
thank you very much

Comment: to your question about GDAXI. Unfortunately it is not a typo. When downloading the DAX from yahoo finance by using getSymbols, you have to use the ticker, which is ^GDAXI